# Django sitemaps 'Post' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a simple django 1.9 app that includes a blog and i want the site to have sitemaps consisting of the website pages and blog post entries.So far i am able to build a sitemap that generates the static pages as sitemaps but the blog post sitemap give me an error `'Post' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url` here is my code.Somebody please tell me where i'm going wrong.

**sitemaps.py**

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps

from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from administration.models import Post


class StaticSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):

      changefreq = "daily"

      priority = 1.0



     def items(self):

          return ['administration:index', 'administration:about']



     def location(self, item):
          return reverse(item)



class PostSitemap(Sitemap):

      changefreq = "daily"

      priority = 0.5


      def items(self):
          return Post.objects.all()`
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'),('published', 'Published'),)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Photos/posts/images", blank=True, null=True)
    post_short_description = models.TextField(default="No description available")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='blog_posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from administration.sitemaps import PostSitemap, StaticSitemap

sitemaps = {
   'post':PostSitemap,'static':StaticSitemap
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('administration.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, 
    name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    url(r'^robots\.txt', include('robots.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls'))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `Sitemap` class and don't implement the `location()` method yourself, the default is to call `get_absolute_url()` on each object.

The docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#a-simple-example say:

> There is no location method in this example, but you can provide it in order to specify the URL for your object. By default, location() calls get_absolute_url() on each object and returns the result.

So you should either implement `location()` on your `PostSitemap`, or implement `get_absolute_url()` on your `Post` model.

Comment: thanks for your help! adding `get_absolute_url` did the trick.

Comment: How did you do the coding for get_absolute_url function?

Comment: @sly_Chandan The simplest method should return something like `f"/posts/{self.id}"`, basically the URL path to your object, or you could construct it using the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/) method, which creates it based on your urls.